# Flutter: "No implementation found for method" - for cached flutter engine

Tags: android, flutter

I want to call a native method from my flutter app but I have an issue:

```
No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel my_channel/name
```

I launch my Flutter app from an existing native Android Application and I want to use some native code from Flutter.

So I use an Flutter engine cache and I register my native method handler but it doesn’t work:

```
        MethodChannel(
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
        "CHANNEL"
    ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        when (call.method) {
            "myMethod" -> {
                doMyNativeCode(call, result)
            }
            else -> {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this code from `Application.onCreate()` when I create flutter engine and put it into cache.

But my `EventChannel's` (listening events from native on flutter) **work well**.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my experience can help you.

My issue was exception on native side:

```
MethodChannel(
    flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
    "CHANNEL"
).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
    when (call.method) {
        "myMethod" -> {
            // THERE WAS EXCEPTION!!!
        }
        else -> {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}
```

}